# Issue On Forgot Password email

Tags: community

getting issue on storefront while setting up forgot password functionality. As a store user when i click on forgot password button and it sends link for setting up new password on my mail and when i click on that link it opened up for the first time its opening the new password set page but when i click on link second or third time its opening the forgot password page. is it configuration error or any other issue ?

Answer (score 0):

This is working as expected and is a security feature from Salesforce to protect your users.

If this is something you need, then you should vote on the following Idea:
[Allow community forgot password reset link to be clicked more than once](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdgW8UAJ/allow-community-forgot-password-reset-link-to-be-clicked-more-than-once)

If the issue you're facing is due to your user's email clients auto expiring links (which is a known issue with the likes of McAfee or corrupted rules in Outlook) then this help article might help too: [Salesforce 'Reset Password' Link Is Expired](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000386502&type=1)